# java access Integer constructor through reflection

Tags: java

I'm having this code. Why doesn't it works?(Working meaning that it display  3) How can I fix it?

```
public class Main {
    public static<V> V copy(V var){
        try{ 
            return (V) var.getClass().getConstructor(var.getClass()).newInstance(var);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Copy faield " + e.getMessage() + " ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer a = new Integer(3);
        Integer b = copy(a);

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);


    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
 Copy faield java.lang.Integer.<init>(java.lang.Integer) 
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Integer.<init>(java.lang.Integer)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2818)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1723)
        at Main.copy(Main.java:7)
        at Main.main(Main.java:19)
    3
    null
```

Thanks!

Comment: Integer only has `int` or `String` argument constructors, no `Integer` copy constructor. With reflection, you cannot unbox the parameters automatically.

Comment: Then why does this works Integer c = new Integer(new Integer(5));

Comment: You are making a lot of assumptions in a generic method here. Not all classes are going to have a constructor that takes a value of the same class.

Comment: @CosminMihai That's because auto unboxing happens from Integer to int automatically there..

Comment: @CosminMihai it works because javac performs an unboxing there. But during reflection you are not passing the `int`'s `Class`, but `Integer`'s, so it cannot do that at runtime.

Comment: try with `int.class` instead of `var.getClass()`

Comment: or try Class.getPrimitiveClass("int"), or Integer.TYPE

Comment: I'm trying to create a generic copy method for classes which have a copy constructor, getPrimitiveClass or int.class would not work, as far as I figure my problem is that Integer does not have a copy constructor. I'm thinking of a workaround

Comment: More importantly: Why do you want to copy an instance of an immutable class? What do you gain if, you have another boxed Integer with the same int value?

Comment: @bali 182 Is meant to be generic, to work for more complex classes which have a copy constructor, but I encountered this problem when I have tested it with Integer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is the distinction between:

```
Integer.class
int.class
```

The constructor for Integer takes an `int` parameter, *not* an `Integer`.

To get your magic method to work, you would need to do a special check of the type, and if it's a wrapper class, actually look for a constructor whose parameter is the corresponding primative type.

AFAIK there's no built in way to get the primatove class from the wrapper class - you could use a map and populate it with the mappings:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> MAP = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(Integer.class, int.class);
    put(Long.class, long.class);
    // etc
}};
```

Then in your method:

```
Class<?> type = MAP.containsKey(var.getClass()) ? MAP.get(var.getClass()) : var.getClass();
return (V) var.getClass().getConstructor(type).newInstance(var);
```

It's OK to pass the `int` as an `Integer` in the parameter value - that at least gets auto unboxed.

Comment: Ok, I understand, thanks. If you have any idea how I could dodge that keeping the purpose of the method generic please share.

Comment: @CosminMihai See code for how to handle elegantly. Merry Xmas :)

Comment: Thank you very much, hope that the corresponding class for char primitive type is Character

Comment: @CosminMihai yes, it is. All wrappers except Integer and Character are the same name as the primative but capitalised.

Answer (score 2):

Generic approach of copying any object to another object. This util class is available in the package - org.apache.commons.lang3.

```
 Integer c = (Integer) SerializationUtils.clone(a);
```

Comment: SerializationUtils is not in the standard library, I was looking for something nice.

Comment: Using a mature library, that is already used by many users and big projects is much nicer, than putting something together in a few hours by yourself. Just my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

To really understand why "new Integer(new Integer(5))" works while reflections doesn't it's useful to look at the generated byte code for the first case:

```
ICONST_5
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Integer.<init> (I)V
INVOKEVIRTUAL java/lang/Integer.intValue ()I
INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Integer.<init> (I)V
```

... as you can see, a call is being made to the intValue() method of Integer "under the hood". So, the java compiler is actually translating your "new Integer(new Integer(5))" to "new Integer(new Integer(5).intValue())". This means it can use the constructor which takes an int.

Because the java compiler cannot know the actual runtime type of the variable for the reflections call it cannot do anything similar and can only look for a constructor with the actual runtime type argument.

Comment: I think i will put some if statements or a switch for Integer, Float, Double and Long classes to resolve those particular cases

Answer (score -1):

int is a type but Integer is a wrapper (class) that use int as an object with many fonction